# Speed up message opening by not downloading large attachments?

Tags: exchange, microsoft-outlook-2013

In our company network we use MS Outlook 2013 and Exchange server.
When opening messages with large attachments (like 10 MB or more) it takes several seconds, even if the message text is very short (a few lines of text).

Is it possible to set Outlook so, that the attachments are downloaded from the server only when the user tries to open/preview or save them?

Comment: Are you certain the problem is attachment size? I have users that work with very large attachments that have no trouble. Does this affect all users? All attachment types? All versions of Outlook? Are there any common culprits shared among the affected users (e.g. Antivirus software)?

Comment: I also receive numerous emails with large attachments and never experience this problem.  What does your Administrator have to say about the behavior?

Comment: It is probably the antivirus (ESET Endpoint 6.5). When paused, small mails (below 100KB) open in about a second, when running, they open in 3-4 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You might wish to implement the [Microsoft Outlook Cache mode](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-on-Cached-Exchange-Mode-7885af08-9a60-4ec3-850a-e221c1ed0c1c), which download everything locally. Additional keep noted that such a delay can be also caused by a local Antivirus client which scan the attachment once you open it. So when you troubleshoot that issue you might wish to uninstall/disable that (but only temporary do not keep that PC unsecured).